# React presentational / container component separation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, containers

Okay, I am trying to make a project using container / presentational components design but I am missing some kind of information or knowledege.

What I am trying to do is to render a component based upon it's parent component's type:

I have this route: `http://localhost:3000/:componentId`

`componentId` has a backend model with a type (`HTML` or `Text`).

So, I guess I could create the `Component` with the following structure:

**page.js**:

```
const HtmlPage = props => {
    return <Fragment>My HTML Component</Fragment>
};

const TextPage = props => {
    return <Fragment>My Text Component</Fragment>
};

// material-ui styles
const HtmlComponent = withStyles(styles)(HtmlPage);
const TextComponent = withStyles(styles)(TextPage);

export {
    HtmlComponent,
    TextComponent
};
```

**index.js**:

```
import {
    HtmlComponent as HtmlPage,
    TextComponent as TextPage
} from './page';

class Component extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { componentType: 'HTML' };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Retrieve model's type from backend
    }

    render() {
        switch(this.state.componentType) {
            case 'HTML':
                return <HtmlPage />;
            case 'Text':
                return <TextPage />;
        }
    }
}

export default Component;
```

So my question is, is this component "split" well formed or I should create multiple components for `HtmlPage` and `TextPage` and then import them on a parent `Component`?

Any comment is appreciated.